# anyway to edit dd-wrt nvram .bin backup ( settings backup) file?

Tags: binary, router, zlib, dd-wrt, haskell-zlib

is there any way to edit the .bin backup ? i found program by nirosoft called "routerpassview" and it decrypted it very well but don't know how to encrypt it again to .bin file and restore settings

### DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION

84            0x54            Zlib compressed data, default compression

it seems pointless but i need it to disable sim lock

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little php script i use for these things. Hope it helps:

```
   #!/usr/bin/php
<?PHP
/*
 * phpnvram - command line editor for DD-WRT nvram-backup
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Markus Quint <markus@dd-wrt.com>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
**/

global $argc, $argv;

if (php_sapi_name() == "cli")
    cli();

function cli()
{
    global $argc, $argv;

    $CMD = array(
        //  command => count parameter
        "get"   => 1,
        "rget"  => 1,
        "fget"  => 2,   // get parameter to file
        "set"   => 1,
        "fset"  => 2,   // set parameter from file
        "unset" => 1,
        "show"  => 0,
        "showkeys"  => 0,
        "diff"  => 1,   // diff bewtween two files
        "vdiff" => 1,   // verbose diff
        "rdiff" => 2,   // diff values matching a regualr expression
        );

    if ($argc < 3 || !file_exists($argv[1]))
        cli_help();

    if (!array_key_exists($argv[2], $CMD))
        cli_help();

    if ( ($argc - 3) < $CMD[$argv[2]] )
        cli_help();

    $nvrambak = new nvram($argv[1]);
    if ($nvrambak->get_errno())
        echo $nvrambak->get_errmsg($nvrambak->get_errno());

    $nvram = $nvrambak->nvram_getconfig();

    $count = $argc - (($argc - 3) - ($CMD[$argv[2]] - 1));
    for ($i=$argc; $i>$count; $i--)
        $pattern[] = $argv[$i-1];

    switch ($argv[2]) {
        case "get":
            $nvrambak->cli_get($nvram, $argv[3]);
            break;
        case "rget":
            $nvrambak->cli_rget($nvram, $pattern);
            break;
        case "fget":
            $nvrambak->cli_fget($nvram, $argv[3], $argv[4]);
            break;
        case "set":
            $nvrambak->cli_set($nvram, $argv[3]);
            break;
        case "fset":
            $nvrambak->cli_fset($nvram, $argv[3], $argv[4]);
            break;
        case "unset":
            $nvrambak->cli_unset($nvram, $argv[3]);
            break;
        case "show":
            $nvrambak->cli_show($nvram);
            break;
        case "showkeys":
            $nvrambak->cli_keys($nvram);
            break;
        case "diff":
            $nvrambak->cli_diff($nvram, $argv[3]);
            break;
        case "vdiff":
            $nvrambak->cli_diff($nvram, $argv[3], true);
            break;
        case "rdiff":
            $nvrambak->cli_rdiff($nvram, $argv[3], $pattern);
            break;
    }

    if ($nvrambak->get_errno())
        echo $nvrambak->get_errmsg($nvrambak->get_errno());
}

function cli_help($cmd="")
{
    global $argv;

    printf("Usage:\n%s <nvrambak.bin> %s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n %37s%s\n",
            $argv[0],
            "[get name]",
            " ", "[rget regex]",
            " ", "[fget name <target-file>]", 
            " ", "[set name=value]",
            " ", "[fset name <source-file>]",
            " ", "[unset name]",
            " ", "[show]",
            " ", "[showkeys]",
            " ", "[diff <nvrambak.bin>]",
            " ", "[vdiff <nvrambak.bin>]",
            " ", "[rdiff <nvrambak.bin> regex]"
            );
    exit();
}

class nvram
{
    const FILE_HEAD = "DD-WRT";

    private $backup_fname;
    private $backup_fhandle;
    private $backup_config = array();

    public function __construct($backup_fname="nvrambak.bin") 
    {
        if ( !($handle = $this->backup_fread($backup_fname, $this->backup_config)) )
            return;

        $this->backup_fname = $backup_fname;
        $this->backup_fhandle = $handle;

        $this->backup_fclose();
        $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS"]);
    }

    /* core functions  **********
     *
     */

    private function backup_fclose()
    {
        if ($this->backup_fhandle) {
            fclose($this->backup_fhandle);
            $this->backup_fhandle = NULL;
        }
    }

    private function backup_fread($fname, &$config_buff)
    {
        if (!$fname || !is_array($config_buff) )
            return 0;

        if (!file_exists($fname)) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["DONT_EXISTS"]);
            return 0;
        }

        $fhandle = fopen($fname, "rb");
        if (!$fhandle) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["CANT_OPENR"]);
            return 0;
        }

        $len = filesize($fname);

        $fhead = fread($fhandle, strlen(self::FILE_HEAD));
        if ($fhead != self::FILE_HEAD) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["NOT_VALID"]);
            return 0;
        }
        $len -= 6;

        $byte = fread($fhandle, 1);
        $data = unpack("H*", $byte);
        $byte = base_convert($data[1], 16, 10);
        $count = $byte;
        $byte = fread($fhandle, 1);
        $data = unpack("H*", $byte);
        $byte = base_convert($data[1], 16, 10);
        $count += ($byte << 8);
        $len -= 2;

        for ($i=0; $i < $count && $len > 0; $i++)
        {
            $byte = fread($fhandle, 1);
            $data = unpack("H*", $byte);
            $slen = base_convert($data[1], 16, 10);

            if ($slen == 0) { // workaround for buggy nvram format
                $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS_WERR"]);
                fread($fhandle, 2);
                $len -= 3;
                continue;
            }

            $name = sprintf("%s", fread($fhandle, $slen));
            $len -= ($slen + 1);

            $byte = fread($fhandle, 1);
            $data = unpack("H*", $byte);
            $byte = base_convert($data[1], 16, 10);
            $slen = $byte;
            $byte = fread($fhandle, 1);
            $data = unpack("H*", $byte);
            $byte = base_convert($data[1], 16, 10);
            $slen += ($byte << 8);
            $len -= ($slen + 2);

            if ($slen > 0)
                $value = fread($fhandle, $slen);
            else
                $value = "";

            $config_buff[$name] = $value;
        }

        if ($this->get_errno() != $this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS_WERR"])
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS"]);

        return $fhandle;
    }

    private function backup_fwrite($fname, $config)
    {
        $fhandle = fopen($fname, "wb");
        if (!$fhandle) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["CANT_OPENW"]);
            return;
        }

        fwrite($fhandle, self::FILE_HEAD, strlen(self::FILE_HEAD));

        $count = count($config);
        $data = base_convert($count & 255, 10, 16);
        fwrite($fhandle, pack("H" . 2, sprintf("%02s", $data)));
        $data = base_convert($count >> 8, 10, 16);
        fwrite($fhandle, pack("H" . 2, sprintf("%02s", $data)));

        foreach ($config AS $name => $value) {
            $len = strlen($name);
            $data = base_convert($len, 10, 16);
            fwrite($fhandle, pack("H" . 2, sprintf("%02s", $data)));
            fwrite($fhandle, $name);

            $len = strlen($value);
            $data = base_convert($len & 255, 10, 16);
            fwrite($fhandle, pack("H" . 2, sprintf("%02s", $data)));
            $data = base_convert($len >> 8, 10, 16);
            fwrite($fhandle, pack("H" . 2, sprintf("%02s", $data)));
            fwrite($fhandle, $value);
        }

        fclose($fhandle);
        $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS"]);
    }

    private function shadow($password)
    {
        $hash = '';
        for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
        {
            $j = mt_rand(0,53);
            if($j<26)$hash .= chr(rand(65,90));
            else if($j<52)$hash .= chr(rand(97,122));
            else if($j<53)$hash .= '.';
            else $hash .= '/';
        }
        return crypt($password,'$1$'.$hash.'$');
    }

    /* programming interface **********
     *
     */

    public function nvram_writeconfig($config, $fname)
    {
        if(!$fname OR !$config OR !is_array($config))
            return;

        $this->backup_fwrite($fname, $config);
    }

    public function nvram_changevalues(&$nvram, $changes)
    {
        if (!$nvram OR !$changes)
            return;

        foreach ($changes AS $name => $value) {
            if ($value === NULL)
                unset($nvram[$name]);
            else
                $nvram[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function nvram_getconfig()
    {
        if (count($this->backup_config))
            return $this->backup_config;
    }

    public function nvram_rget($nvram, $pattern)
    {
        if (!$nvram || !$pattern)
            return;

        $config = $this->nvram_getconfig();

        foreach($config AS $name => $value) {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($pattern); $i++)
                if (preg_match($pattern[$i], $name))
                    $result[$name] = $value;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function nvram_diff($nvram, $diff_fname)
    {
        $diff_config = array();
        $this->backup_fread($diff_fname, $diff_config);
        if ($this->get_errno()) {
            echo $this->get_errmsg($this->get_errno());
        }

        $result = array("identic" => array(),
                        "different" => array(),
                        "orig_only" => array(),
                        "diff_only" => array(),
                        );

        foreach($nvram AS $name => $value)
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($name, $diff_config))
                $result["orig_only"][$name] = $value;
            else {
                if ($nvram[$name] == $diff_config[$name])
                    $result["identic"][$name] = $value;
                else {
                    $result["different"][$name][$this->backup_fname] = $value;
                    $result["different"][$name][$diff_fname] = $diff_config[$name];
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($diff_config AS $name => $value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($name, $nvram))
                $result["diff_only"][$name] = $value;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function nvram_rdiff($nvram, $diff_fname, $pattern)
    {
        if (!$nvram || !$diff_fname || !$pattern)
            return;

        $full_diff = $this->nvram_diff($nvram, $diff_fname);

        foreach($full_diff AS $class => $list) {
            foreach($list AS $name => $value) {
                for ($i=0; $i<count($pattern); $i++)
                    if (preg_match($pattern[$i], $name))
                        $result[$class][$name] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function nvram_fromfile($fname)
    {
        if (!$fname)
            return;

        if (!file_exists($fname)) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["FILE_EXISTS"]);
            return;
        }

        $fhandle = fopen($fname, "rb");
        if (!$fhandle) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["CANT_OPENR"]);
            return;
        }

        $value = fread($fhandle, filesize($fname));

        $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS"]);
        fclose($fhandle);

        return $value;
    }


    /* commandline functions **********
     *
     */

    public function cli_get($nvram, $name)
    {
        if (!$nvram OR !$name)
            return;

        if (count($nvram))
            printf("%s\n", $nvram[$name]);
    }

    public function cli_rget($nvram, $pattern)
    {
        if (!$nvram || !$pattern)
            return;

        $result = $this->nvram_rget($nvram, $pattern);
        print_r($result);
    }

    public function cli_fget($nvram, $name, $fname)
    {
        if (!$name || !$fname)
            return;

        if (file_exists($fname)) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["FILE_EXISTS"]);
            return;
        }

        $fhandle = fopen($fname, "wb+");
        if (!$fhandle) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["CANT_OPENW"]);
            return;
        }

        if ( fwrite($fhandle, $nvram[$name], strlen($nvram[$name])) )
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS"]);

        fclose($fhandle);
        return;
    }

    public function cli_set(&$nvram, $namevalue)
    {
        if (!$nvram OR !$namevalue)
            return;

        if (count($nvram))
        {
            // gibts nicht mehr seit php7
            // $set = split("=", $namevalue);
            $set = explode("=", $namevalue,2);
            $name = $set[0];
            $value = substr($namevalue,strlen($set[0])+1);

            if ($name == "http_username" || $name == "http_passwd")
                $nvram[$name] = $this->shadow($value);
            else
                $nvram[$name] = $value;
        }
        $this->backup_fwrite($this->backup_fname, $nvram);
    }

    public function cli_unset(&$nvram, $name)
    {
        if (!$nvram OR !$name)
            return;

        if (count($nvram))
            unset($nvram[$name]);

        $this->backup_fwrite($this->backup_fname, $nvram);
    }

    public function cli_show($nvram)
    {
        if (count($nvram))
            foreach ($nvram AS $name => $value)
                printf ("%s=%s\n", $name, $value);
    }

    public function cli_keys($nvram)
    {
        if (count($nvram)) {
            foreach ($nvram AS $name => $value)
                printf ("%s\n", $name);
        }
    }

    public function cli_diff($nvram, $d_fname, $full=false)
    {
        $result = $this->nvram_diff($nvram, $d_fname);

        if ($full) {
            echo "Identical:\n";
            print_r ($result["identic"]);
            echo "\n";
        }
        echo "Only in $this->backup_fname\n";
        ksort($result["orig_only"]);
        print_r($result["orig_only"]);
        echo "\nOnly in $d_fname\n";
        ksort($result["diff_only"]);
        print_r($result["diff_only"]);
        echo "\nDifferences:\n";
        ksort($result["different"]);
        print_r($result["different"]);
    }

    public function cli_rdiff($nvram, $d_fname, $pattern)
    {
        if (!$nvram || !$d_fname || !$pattern)
            return;

        $full_diff = $this->nvram_rdiff($nvram, $d_fname, $pattern);

        print_r($full_diff);
    }

/*
    public function cli_fset($nvram, $name, $fname)
    {
        if (!$name || !$fname)
            return;

        if (!file_exists($fname)) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["DONT_EXISTS"]);
            return;
        }

        $fhandle = fopen($fname, "rb");
        if (!$fhandle) {
            $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["CANT_OPENR"]);
            return;
        }

        $nvram[$name] = fread($fhandle, filesize($fname));
        $this->backup_fwrite($this->backup_fname, $nvram);

        $this->set_error($this->ERR_NO["SUCCESS"]);

        fclose($fhandle);
        return;
    }
*/
    /* misc **********
     *
     */

    public function strcrypt($passwd)
    {
        if ($passwd)
            return $this->shadow($passwd);
        return "";
    }


    /* error **********
     *
     */

    private $err_errno;
    private $err_errmsg;

    private $ERR_NO = array("SUCCESS"       => 0,
                            "DONT_EXISTS"   => 1,
                            "CANT_OPENR"    => 2,
                            "NOT_VALID"     => 3,
                            "SUCCESS_WERR"  => 4,
                            "CANT_OPENW"    => 5,
                            "FILE_EXISTS"   => 6,
                        );
    private $ERR_MSG = array(0 => "Success\n",
                             1 => "File not found\n",
                             2 => "Could not open file for reading\n",
                             3 => "File is not a valid nvram-backup\n",
                             4 => "Success, but skipped faulty null-param\n",
                             5 => "Could not open file for writing\n",
                             6 => "File already exists\n",
                         );
 
    private function set_error($err_no)
    {
        $this->err_errno = $err_no;
        $this->err_errmsg = $this->ERR_MSG[$err_no];
    }

    public function get_errno()
    {
        return $this->err_errno;
    }

    public function get_errmsg()
    {
        return $this->err_errmsg;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: tnx , someone finally answered !!! , but how can i use it ? php file.php?